# Use non-latin alphabets in dynamic textfields

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I'm trying to translate my app in a few languages, but i'm having trouble with non-latin alphabets. (I'm working with Flash CC, my app is Air for Android)
I'm not a pro so I had to improvize for localization: the user clicks the button corresponding to his/r language and it updates a variable (lang=1 for french, lang=2 for english, etc.).

```
if (lang==1){
    textField.text="Salut";
else if (lang==2{
    textField.text="Hi";
//and so on
}
```

It's probably the ugliest way to do it but it works. I'd also like to be able to translate my app to japanese, arabic and maybe russian. 
I've tried to copy/paste the arabic text in the textfield, it works, but not when i paste it in my code. I've read online that you could do it up to Flash CS6 thanks to TFL textfields, but (whatever they were) they do not exist anymore in CC.
Anyone know how to do this? 
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use any characters in dynamic TextField you should embed these characters by clicking "Embed..." in properties panel and choosing all characters you will use in this text field. For example, for Japanese you should check at least one checkbox:[image]
Also, you should choose Font Family and Style.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I already have the relevant glyphs checked in Embed, but when I test the app, the textField is blank (the text appears in latin alphabet when I switch to french). Maybe it comes from the code? I use : textField.text = "敵"; There might an additional step i do not know?

Comment: Probably, your font (e.g. Arial.ttf) doesn't have 敵 symbol. I checked all Chinese checkboxes in “Embed” window, but this symbol not visible. Arial font on my computer doesn't has this symbol.

Comment: Try to find a font with Chinese, Japanese and other symbols.